# Fluid images, resizing window

Tags: php

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
                            @media(min-width: 640px){
                                .<?php echo $champion[$i];?>{
                                background-image: url('<?php if($summary!=1){echo 'assets/champions/'.$champion[$i];}else{echo '../../../assets/champions/'.$champion[$i];} ?>_pc.jpg');

                                }
                            }
                            @media(max-width: 639px){
                                .<?php echo $champion[$i]; ?>{
                                background-image: url('<?php if($summary!=1){echo 'assets/champions/'.$champion[$i];}else{echo '../../../assets/champions/'.$champion[$i];} ?>_mobile.jpg');

                                }
                            }
```

http://i.imgur.com/qSlAfDF.png
http://i.imgur.com/iAEJRNk.png

Above are pictures showing the problem I'm curious what's the best way to make this responsive and not look crappy after resizing. I thought about cropping in 3rd software from splash art the way that champion's face would be in the middle so it will always be visible.`enter code here`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Comment: `background-position: center;` or `background-size: cover` might be a good place to start?

Comment: background-position: center; helped but is there any way to make the image resize from left to right not from right to left?